# Ubuntu adding a user not setting a home directory

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to add a user in ubuntu using the following command, but the home directory is not getting created.

```
sudo useradd -p $(openssl passwd -1 MyPassWord) myUserName
```

But it doesn't seem to add a home directory by default. What should I add to get a home directory created for the user by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is right there in the man page for `useradd(8)`:

```
   -m, --create-home
       Create the user's home directory if it does not exist. The files and directories contained
       in the skeleton directory (which can be defined with the -k option) will be copied to the
       home directory.

       By default, if this option is not specified and CREATE_HOME is not enabled, no home
       directories are created.
```